# Use PHPUnit by HTTP as default test run configuration

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I'm trying to configure my PhpStorm 2016.1 to run tests on remote machine. I have PHPUnit installed on dev machine (Windows Server 2012) and web server one (Ubuntu server). I can create "PHPUnit by HTTP" run configuration and then run this configuration. But I want to be able to run test of selected class. And when I open a context menu on a file I can choose "Run" and then temporary run configuration of "PHPUnit" type is created.

PhpStorm help states I have to expand "Create run configuration" context menu item and then choose run configuration type I want. However I have no "Create run configuration" menu item at all. And I could find no single mention of choosing run configuration type for selected file/class or setting default run configuration type.

I have no PHP installed on Dev machine, so running PHPUnit tests locally isn't an option at all. How can I set "PHPUnit by HTTP" as default or single option?

Comment: Not 100% sure on your issue (PHPUnit by HTTP) .. but you can create Remote PHP Interpreter (using SFTP details) and then execute PHPUnit tests on remote machine via SSH. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However I tried it already. I have to test components as if they were invoked by HTTP requests with appropriate environment variables received via Apache. Therefore remote interpreter isn't an option as well.